# Mod-Rewrite in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a beginner to mod_rewrite.
I am trying to build a website for a club, and I think using mod_rewrite would pretty up the urls a bit.
Anyway, the page currently is under development, so I have placed it in a subdirectory. 
To access my page I would browse to mydomain.com/minisite/club/alpha.

Within this directory, my index.php page asks for an id in which to return a page. so mydomain.com/minisite/club/alpha/index.php?id=1 would return the first page.

I would like the page to appear as .mydomain.com/minisite/club/alpha/page/1/.

Please refer to any useful documentation that I could read to better understand mod_rewrite,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to your .htaccess file in the root directory of your folder. If you already have rules there, add this rule at the top.

```
#if these 2 lines already exist skip them
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#this rule should before other RewriteCond/RewriteRules in your .htaccess
RewriteRule ^minisite/club/alpha/page/([0-9]+) minisite/club/alpha/index.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Here are some resources for .htaccess: [Introduction to htaccess](http://ulrichpalha.com/myblog/2011/11/26/improve-your-sites-seo-with-basic-url-rewriting-redirects-using-mod_rewrite-in-htaccess/),  [htaccess Tricks](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/), [Apache Docs on Htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: Great, Thank you.
Now just getting the pesky style sheets and images working. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the alpha folder (where index.php is located), create a .htaccess with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*?)/*$ index.php?id=$1
```

This allows you to browse to both `.../page/1` aswell as `.../page/1/`

Comment: That didn't work. Maybe conflicting .htaccess file?
I have an .htaccess file above in mydomain.com/ :
'RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).htm$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]'

Comment: Possibly, move this RewriteRule line to that file, and modify it to include the full path i.e.: `RewriteRule ^/minisite/club/alpha/page/(.*?)/*$ /minisite/club/alpha/index.php?id=$1` and play with it until it works with the other rules, its a bit messy sometimes with more than one rule so try moving it around and group differently in that toplevel .htaccess one. Good luck!